# Excel export does not work only on Chrome browser

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

Client: Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 m
ContentType: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"

Excel export used to work till last Chrome update. It works well on Firefox and IE. When I hit export, a file with no extension downloads. If I manually change extension of this file to .xlsx then it opens in excel.

Comment: Anyone else encountering this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, adding ".xlsx" extension to file name helped. Please leave comment in case of a better solution. Thanks.

```
public virtual ActionResult Download(string fName) { 
    var fileStream = Session[fName] as MemoryStream; 
    Session[fName] = null; 
    return File(fileStream, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "ExcelExport.xlsx"); 
}
```